# Generators of the orthogonal group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, orthogonal-matrices

The real orthogonal group $O(N) = \{ A \in GL(N,\mathbb{R})|A^TA = AA^T = 1 \}$ consists of rotations with $\det A = +1$ (forming the subgroup $SO(N)$) and of reflections with $\det A = -1$. Its algebra is given by the skew-symmetric matrices $\mathfrak{o}(N) = \{ G \in GL(N,\mathbb{R})|G^T = -G \}$. Therefore each element of $O(N)$ should be generated by an element of $\mathfrak{o}(N)$ via a matrix exponential
\begin{equation}
A = \exp G.
\end{equation}
It is easy to check that $A$ is indeed orthogonal. However, its determinant is always
\begin{equation}
\det A = \det \exp G = \exp \text{tr}\ G = +1,
\end{equation}
because skew-symmetric matrices are traceless $\text{tr}\ G = 0$. Therefore we only generate $SO(N)$. Where is my error?

Comment: You have no error.  The Lie algebra of a Lie group can only generate the (path) connected component of the identity via $\exp$ by virtue of the fact that $t \rightarrow \exp{tX}$ describes a path from the identity to the element you're trying to reach.

Comment: The exponential map is not surjective in general. It will automatically fail to be surjective when the group is not connected, as is the case here, but it may even fail for some connected groups. Connectedness+compactness is sufficient, though.